# how to merge small files in all leaf node under a folder on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have many small files(text file and parquet file) in the leaf node (such as /aaa/bbb/ccc/x/x1.txt, /aaa/bbb/ccc/x/x2.txt,... and /aaa/bbb/ccc/t/dt=xxxx-xx-xx/part-00000, /aaa/bbb/ccc/t/dt=xxxx-xx-xx/part-00001,...) under a folder(/aaa/bbb/ccc/), Now I need merge small files(such as <10MB) into a single file in all the leaf node. Is there any good way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: What's a leaf node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest merging all files less than 128MB or whatever your block size is. If you think 10M is large enough, then you're mistaken.

There are several ways to do this. If you have Hive, Spark, or Pig, just load the files and write them somewhere else.

If not, you can use a `hadoop distcp` job to execute a MapReduce job that'll read the files and rewrite them into a different folder within the same cluster,  typically writing in larger sizes. This is even a pattern given by Amazon EMR documentation.

If these files continously arrive, use an Oozie workflow to repeat the process over time